# How can I run a controller function only after textarea fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textarea like below:

```
<textarea rows="3" maxlength="144" ng-maxlength="144" type="text"
          name="testPost" id="testPost_{{item.id}}"
          ng-init="focusText('testPost', item.id)"
          ng-model="item.testPost">
</textarea>
```

with a function like below:

```
$scope.focusText = function (columnSelected, id){
    if(columnSelected == "testPost"){
        var textId = "testPost_" + id;
        document.getElementById(textId).focus();
        document.getElementById(textId).setSelectionRange(0,0);
    } 
}
```

The problem is, `document.getElementById(textId)` is `null` as function is ran before the textarea is loaded. How can I run the function only after textarea is loaded?

Comment: change the way you are generating id as below and try
id="{{'testPost_'+item.id}}"

Comment: @daddygames it won't work that way. it means I need to focus on the textarea for the cursor to appear. What i did was have an ng-if so when a button is clicked, the textarea will show and a cursor should appear in the textarea.

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS no. it is still the same

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, `document.getElementById(textId)` is `null`

Create a custom directive:

```
app.directive("myInit", function() {
   return {
       link: postLink
   };
   function postLink(scope, element, attrs)
       scope.$eval(attrs.myInit, {$element: element})
   }
})
```

Then pass the `$element` local to the function:

```
<textarea rows="3" maxlength="144" ng-maxlength="144" type="text"
          name="testPost" id="testPost_{{item.id}}"
          my-init="focusText('testPost', item.id, $element)"
          ng-model="item.testPost">
</textarea>
```

Use the `$element` parameter in the `focusText` function:

```
$scope.focusText = function (columnSelected, id, $element){
    if(columnSelected == "testPost"){
        $element[0].focus();
        $element[0].setSelectionRange(0,0);
    } 
}
```

This avoids using `document.getElementById` and the error.